# Removing certain columns from a text file

Tags: macos, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B
G   T   C   A   G   T   C   A   G   T   C
A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B
A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B
A   D   E   A   B   D   E   A   B   D   E
A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B
C   B   D   G   C   B   D   G   C   B   D
```

Is there a way to extract only certain columns and leave the other columns intact?

For example removing only columns 2 and 5:

```
A   C   A   C   A   B   C   A   B
G   C   A   T   C   A   G   T   C
A   C   A   C   A   B   C   A   B
A   C   A   C   A   B   C   A   B
A   E   A   D   E   A   B   D   E
A   C   A   C   A   B   C   A   B
C   D   G   B   D   G   C   B   D
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Found this answer using awk, but this extract whole "block" of columns and I only want to extract some.

Awk for extracting columns 3 to 5:

```
awk -F 'FS' 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{for (i=1; i<=NF-1; i++) if(i<3 || i>5) {printf $i FS};{print $NF}}' input.txt
```

Comment: FAQ.  Various `awk` examples exist.  Try searching.

Comment: I just checked the answers using awk, but they only extract "block" of columns, and I want to delete columns that are not necessarily adjacent.

Comment: Depending on how many columns you want to print, you can use `print $1,$2,$4,$6,…` but that can be tedious, or something like `$3="";$5="";print $0;` if you don't care about the output format

Answer (score 0):

in your case you could do

```
cat your_file |cut -d ' ' --complement -s -f2,5
```

where ' ' is the delimiter(in your case the space)

Comment: I get an error of illegal option. I am working on OSX